# regex match exact occurance of special character

Tags: regex, linux, grep

File:

```
cat test.txt

100 ***

10 ** // target
```

Grep:

```
grep -E '\*{2}' test.txt

100 ***

10 **
```

Isn't the `{m}` used to do exact the number of the match?

How to get the `*` with exact 2 occurrence?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you are too fast. I intended to ask about the special character. the \b does not work. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -E '(^|[^*])\*{2}($|[^*])' test.txt
```

See [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/ozQwFc):

```
test="100 ***
10 ** // target"
grep -E '(^|[^*])\*{2}($|[^*])' <<< "$test"
# => 10 ** // target
```

**Details**

- `(^|[^*])` - start of string or any char but `*`
- `\*{2}` - two asterisks
- `($|[^*])` - end of string or any char but `*`.

**Variation with whitespace boundaries**

If you need to only match a "word" in between spaces use

```
grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])\*{2}($|[[:space:]])' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple *basic* regular expression will work as well explicitly specifying `"**"` not surrounded by a `'*'`. For example:

```
$ grep '^[^*]*[*][*][^*]*$' test.txt
10 **
```

That will match the line containing `[*][*]` anywhere in the line not surrounded by another `'*'`.